# How to implement server-side sever name indication using Security.framework under OS X/iOS

Tags: ios, macos, ssl, server

I am trying to implement server name indication on the server side of a `OS X` application: The server should pick a certificate based on the peer host name provided by the client. 
Does anybody know whether this can be achieved using the `Security.framework`? 
`SSLSetCertificate` takes only one leaf certificate and I cannot find any callback for providing a certificate based on a host name.

In openSSL for example, there is the SSL_CTX_set_tlsext_servername_callback for this purpose.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think under El Capitan, the following SSL session option might do the trick: `kSSLSessionOptionBreakOnClientHello` together with the handshake error code `errSSLClientHelloReceived`. The problem is that there is no documentation on this feature and the source code for the El Capitan security framework it is not yet available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a new feature in `OS X 10.11` (El Capitan) which makes this possible. Sadly, there is currently zero documentation on this feature, but I nevertheless found out how it works:

You have to enable the new option `kSSLSessionOptionBreakOnClientHello` on your SSL context with:

```
SSLSetSessionOption(context, kSSLSessionOptionBreakOnClientHello, YES);
```

This causes the handshake to break after is has received the hostname from the client and it returns the status `errSSLClientHelloReceived`. You can then get the hostname, use it to look up the appropriate certificate and apply the certificate to the context. Then you can continue the handshake.

```
OSStatus status = SSLHandshake(context);

// ...

if(status == errSSLClientHelloReceived) 
{
    size_t hostnameLength;
    SSLGetPeerDomainNameLength(context, &hostnameLength);
    char hostname[hostnameLength];
    SSLGetPeerDomainName(context, hostname, &hostnameLength);

    SecIdentityRef cert = ... ; // Look up certificate using hostname

    SSLSetCertificate(context, (__bridge CFArrayRef)@[(__bridge id) cert]);

    // Repeat from start by calling SSLHandshake 
}
```

Comment: I have just heard from Apple developer support that it is an artifact of the implementation that `SSLGetPeerDomainName` currently returns the correct hostname and that it is likely to break in the future. They told me that the correct function call would be `SSLCopyRequestedPeerName` which sadly is private API at the moment. So we have the choice of using the wrong but working API or a private API. Both are likely to break in future OS versions. I decided to go with the private API as I am working on an OS X app which does not need to be sold in the App Store.